# How to write an Edit Action

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to come up with an edit action. See below for what i have so far.

**ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GlobalUnitedSC.WebUI.Models
{
public sealed class CreateMensPlayerViewModel
{
    //Player profile starts here

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int MensTeamId { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Position { get; set; }

    public int ShirtNumber { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Joined { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    //Player Statistics starts here
    public int Games { get; set; }
    public int Goals { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    public int TotalShots { get; set; }
    public int ShotsOnGoal { get; set; }
    public int FoulsDrawn { get; set; }
    public int FoulsCommitted { get; set; }
    public int Saves { get; set; }
    public int BlueCards { get; set; }
    public int YellowCards { get; set; }
    public int RedCards { get; set; }
 }
}
```

**Create Actions:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(int mensTeamId)
    {
        new CreateMensPlayerViewModel {MensTeamId = mensTeamId};

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateMensPlayerViewModel viewModel, HttpPostedFileBase  image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var mensTeam = _dataSource.MensTeams.Single(t => t.Id == viewModel.MensTeamId);
            var mensPlayer = new MensPlayer
                                 {
                                     Name = viewModel.Name,
                                     BirthDate = viewModel.BirthDate,
                                     Position = viewModel.Position,
                                     ShirtNumber = viewModel.ShirtNumber,
                                     Joined = viewModel.Joined,
                                     Country = viewModel.Country,
                                     Description = viewModel.Description,
                                     EmailAddress = viewModel.EmailAddress,
                                     PhoneNumber = viewModel.PhoneNumber,
                                     Games = viewModel.Games,
                                     Goals = viewModel.Goals,
                                     Assists = viewModel.Assists,
                                     TotalShots = viewModel.TotalShots,
                                     ShotsOnGoal = viewModel.ShotsOnGoal,
                                     FoulsDrawn = viewModel.FoulsDrawn,
                                     FoulsCommitted = viewModel.FoulsCommitted,
                                     Saves = viewModel.Saves,
                                     BlueCards = viewModel.BlueCards,
                                     YellowCards = viewModel.YellowCards,
                                     RedCards = viewModel.RedCards
                                 };

            mensTeam.MensPlayers.Add(mensPlayer);

            _dataSource.Save();
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", mensPlayer.Name);

            return RedirectToAction("detail", "MensTeam", new {id =         viewModel.MensTeamId});
        }

        return View(viewModel); 
    }
```

**HttpGet Edit Action**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit (int id)
    {
        var mensPlayer = _dataSource.MensPlayers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

        return View(mensPlayer);
    }
```

Now could anyone please help me with the HttpPost Edit action, preferably one based on the model class mentioned above?

I was hoping it has something to do with the line below, if this creates a new player, what could i write to edit that player?

```
var mensPlayer = new MensPlayer {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Slauma in the comments in the repost or extension of this question at:

[Repost/Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962737/edit-method-in-mvc4-and-visual-studio-2012/12964463#12964463)

This is what he suggested i do and it works.

Add to IDataSource Interface:

```
 void Update(MensPlayer mensPlayer);
```

Update Implemented in Db class:

```
void IDataSource.Update(MensPlayer mensPlayer)
    {
        Entry(mensPlayer).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Edit Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MensPlayer mensPlayer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save Player
            _dataSource.Update(mensPlayer);
           _dataSource.Save();

           TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", mensPlayer.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", "MensPlayer", new {id = mensPlayer.Id});
        }
        return View(mensPlayer);
    }
```

And Just like that all works fine, although i was under the assumption that i would implement Update to the whole DbSet like i did with Save.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a post the method is kind of equal to your create-method. You will receive a MensPlayer as a parameter.

Than you check if the Model is valid (validation etc.) and flag the entry as modified and save the changes.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel myModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        DbContext.Entry(myModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(myModel);
}
```

DBContext

```
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyModel> MyModelSet{ get; set; }
}
```

[More info about DBContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there something special i am supposed to do with this line? `DbContext.Entry(myModel).State = EntityState.Modified;` To start Entry is flagged, do i need to create a stub in my datasource?

Comment: No, The DBContext should be the same as the var you mention as _datasource as I see it!

Comment: Oh i get that very well, its just that i have never used "Entry" before and i can't seem to find a C# reference for it. And also, appears red on my code which means i am missing something or there is something i am supposed to add for code to compile. Also noticed that this is straight from the MVC-Music-Store app. I already considered that option.

Comment: I updated the answer with the definition for my DBContext. As it inherits from DBContext, who contains the Entry, there should be no compilation errors.

Comment: I know about DbContext, how else would i have created the Create method.

Comment: Oh, seems that I have misread your post. Sorry. You're using Code First approach? In that case you might have to add the reference. Try adding System.Data.Entity by right-clicking the reference-cat, you'll find it in the .NET-tab.