# Edit Method in MVC4 and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Could someone please help me with the question i posted late last night. I am still stuck with the edit method. Link below:

[Last night question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949409/how-to-write-an-edit-action/12949879#comment17556226_12949879)

In addition to what was posted, i have also tried:

HttpPost Edit:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MensPlayer mensPlayer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save Player
            _dataSource.Entry(mensPlayer).State = EntityState.Modified;
           _dataSource.Save();

           TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", mensPlayer.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", "MensPlayer", new {id = mensPlayer.Id});
        }
        return View(mensPlayer);
    }
```

The Issue with the above method is around `Entry(mensPlayer).State`, code will not build at .Entry() and i don't seem to know where this method is being inherited. Mind you, this is the technique used in MVC-Music-Store sample.

I have also tried this technique from Pro ASP.NET MVC3 Framework book.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MensPlayer mensPlayer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save Player
           _dataSource.Save();

           TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", mensPlayer.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", "MensPlayer", new {id = mensPlayer.Id});
        }
        return View(mensPlayer);
    }
```

This technique builds but doesn't seem to save changes to the database.

How can i make it work? What am i missing?

**The entire source code is on GitHub if anyone needs to look at the entire solution.**

[GitHub](https://github.com/komengem/GlobalUnitedSC)

With Slauma's help below i have now modified as follows:

Added `void Update();` to IDataSource and added the following to the Db class

```
 void IDataSource.Update()
    {
        Entry(MensPlayers).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

HttpPost Edit:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MensPlayer mensPlayer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save Player
            _dataSource.Update();
           _dataSource.Save();

           TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", mensPlayer.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", "MensPlayer", new {id = mensPlayer.Id});
        }
        return View(mensPlayer);
    }
```

All builds but then i get this error
**The entity type DbSet`1 is not part of the model for the current context.**

Which is believed to originate from:

```
void IDataSource.Update()
    {
        Entry(MensPlayers).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Comment: `Entry` is a method of `DbContext` (and derived classes). Your variable `_dataSource` doesn't seem to be a `DbContext` (or a derived class) because `DbContext` doesn't have a `Save` method. So, what is the type of `_dataSource`?

Comment: I have `void Save();` in my DataSource interface and `void IDataSource.Save()
        {
            SaveChanges();
        }` in my Db file which is derived from both DbContext and my DataSource class. `public class GlobalUnitedScDb : DbContext, IDataSource {}`

Comment: It's considered very poor form to create a new question to add additional information to a previous question.  You should have just edited the first question to include the new info.  This forces people to go back to a different question to understand the context of this one.

Comment: And what is `_dataSource`? Is it declared as `IDataSource`? In that case you will have to extend this interface to support setting the state or updating, for example by adding a method `void SetStateToModified(object entity)` which you would implement with `Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified` and then call in your Edit action as `_dataSource.SetStateToModified(mensPlayer);`, or similar...

Comment: @Slauma Oh sorry, yes _dataSource is declared as IDataSource. Let me try what you just suggested.

Comment: @Slauma Can i do this without parameters like i did with `Save();` so it works with all entities? and if so, what do i call when i implement the method in the Db class? with `void Save();` i have `void IDataSource.Save()
        {
            SaveChanges();
        }` implemented with `SaveChanges();` from DbContext

Comment: I suggest that you edit a sketch of your architecture with that interface, implementation, etc. into your question. The comment section here is not a good place for this.

Comment: @Slauma Please read above to some of the changes i have made. Thanks

Comment: Argh, what are you doing? You must pass in the variable `mensPlayer` (the *entity*) from the action method into `Update` and `Entry` finally, not the whole `DbSet`. The `Update` method **must** have a parameter.

Comment: @Slauma Yes that works and thanks. However, i was wondering if there is a way to this with the whole DbSet so i don't have to have a separate Update method for each entity? Like i have done with Save?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You must decide which entity you want to set the state to `Modified` for.

Comment: @Slauma okay, thank you very much. I will scrub up an answer in a few minutes or if you like you can scrub one up and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Slauma in the comments above this is what he suggested i do and it works.

Add to IDataSource Interface:

```
 void Update(MensPlayer mensPlayer);
```

Update Implemented in Db class:

```
void IDataSource.Update(MensPlayer mensPlayer)
    {
        Entry(mensPlayer).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Edit Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MensPlayer mensPlayer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Save Player
            _dataSource.Update(mensPlayer);
           _dataSource.Save();

           TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", mensPlayer.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", "MensPlayer", new {id = mensPlayer.Id});
        }
        return View(mensPlayer);
    }
```

And Just like that all works fine, although i was under the assumption that i could implement Update to the whole DbSet like i did with Save.